# how to debug pure assembly ARM code in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, arm

I can debug ARM C code (Cortex-M3) in eclipse based on http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/qemu-debugging/ but when I try to debug a pure assembly code the Step Into icon is grayed and the Disassembly View is empty.

The C project constains two simple file (startup.S and main.c), the debugger is working.

The asm project constains two simple file (startup.S and main.S), the main.S is the assembly version of main.c. The asm project is compiled and there is a symbol main.

Is there any special settingss for the assembly debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I have added this to asm version of main, and now works.

```
    .type    main, %function
```